# Programatically detect if I'm in VirtualBox seamless mode

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a way to detect whether I'm in VirtualBox's seamless mode from a guest machine? Or is there any command line option from VBoxControl.exe to detect this that I'm not seeing?

If that can't happen, can I programatically detect if a guest is in seamless mode from the host?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways;

1. check what API access you have to the information reported by the device manager; if you are on a VBox guest, you'll find a couple of unusual devices (VBOX CD-ROM, VirtualBox Graphics Adapter, VBOX HARDDISK, VirtualBox system device). Already the PC's hostname is "VIRTUALBOX".
2. Another, quite similar source of information is the systeminfo command. Also there, several  specific parameters would contain names or values defined by VBox
3. You could also check if VBox additions are installed; they leave trace in the program directory, in the registry `reg:\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox Guest Additions` and as a running task in the task manager.

Comment: that would tell if im running in a guest, but how do i tell whether that guest is seamless moded?